# Extending lifetime of initlist

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, llvm, initializer-list

I have a test case where the lifetime of initlist is extended.

```
#include <initializer_list> 
extern "C" void abort();
bool ok; 
bool do_throw; 
struct A { 
    A(int) { 
    if (do_throw) throw 42; 
    } 
    ~A() { 
     if (!ok) abort(); 
     } 
   }; 

 typedef std::initializer_list<A> AL;
 typedef std::initializer_list<AL> AL2; 
 typedef std::initializer_list<AL2> AL3; 

 struct B { 
      AL al; 
      const AL& alr; 
     }; 

 int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
   do_throw = (argc > 1);        // always false, but optimizer can't tell 
   AL ar[] = {{1,2},{3,4}};  
   B b = {{5,6},{7,8}}; 
   AL3 al3 = {{{1},{2},{3}}}; 
   ok = true; 
   }
```

Here, the initialization of object b should succeed as the lifetime of its subobject al (which is an init list) is extended. When i compile the code with gcc it succeeds, but clang 3.3 throws error. Clang 3.4 succeeds. I went through the code changes from clang 3.3 to 3.4 but unable to determine which revision exactly fixed this. Can someone point to the exact revision number?

Comment: What is the error you're getting from clang 3.3?

Comment: I am getting error : reference to type 'const AL' (aka 'const initializer_list<A>') could not bind to an rvalue of type 'int'